# Implement Umbraco membership provider in another site

Tags: asp.net-membership, umbraco

I've currently got an Umbraco 4.7.1 site with membership setup which is working great.

Now I want to use the umbraco membership provider in another non-umbraco site..  I have a customer that has some .net and classic asp sites and they want a single source for membership information.

I haven't found any successful implementations or examples that work..

Has anyone that can share, got this to work ???

I got close, but I'm getting a stackoverflow error when I hit "log in" button on the asp.net login control.

Thanks

Comment: Are you using any custom properties on your Umbraco membership types?  Or are they vanilla (email, login, password)?

Comment: Did you use the internal Umbraco membership system or a custom one? If you are using the internal membership system you will have to write a custom provider. Extend your membership provider class with umbraco.providers.members.UmbracoMembershipProvider. This is however a quite developer intensive task.

Comment: @BeaverProj - I have a  plain vanilla umbraco membership setup.

Comment: @Trikks, I used the standard umbraco membership system.  If I have to extend the membership provider class I'll need to do more research on this as I've never really worked with the membership provider before.

Comment: FIXED..!!!!  just trying to figure out how to post the answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the pieces of my working web.config

```
<connectionStrings>
<remove name="MySqlConnection" />
<add name="MySqlConnection" connectionString="server=localhost;database=MSSM;user id=db_user;password=password" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

```
<membership defaultProvider="UmbracoMembershipProvider" userIsOnlineTimeWindow="15">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="UmbracoMembershipProvider"
         type="umbraco.providers.members.UmbracoMembershipProvider"
         enablePasswordRetrieval="false" 
         enablePasswordReset="false" 
         requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" 
         defaultMemberTypeAlias="Another Type" 
         passwordFormat="Hashed" />
    <add name="UsersMembershipProvider" 
         type="umbraco.providers.UsersMembershipProvider" 
         enablePasswordRetrieval="false" 
         enablePasswordReset="false" 
         requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" 
         passwordFormat="Hashed" />
  </providers>
</membership>
<roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="UmbracoRoleProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="UmbracoRoleProvider" type="umbraco.providers.members.UmbracoRoleProvider" />
  </providers>
</roleManager>

<roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="UmbracoRoleProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="UmbracoRoleProvider" type="umbraco.providers.members.UmbracoRoleProvider" />
  </providers>
</roleManager>

<appSettings>
<add key="umbracoDbDSN" value="server=localhost;database=MSSM;user id=db_user;password=password" />
```

The next piece to the puzzle is to copy the umbracoSettings.config file from my working umbraco site into a "config" directory under my .net site.

```
/config/umbracoSettings.config
```

It now works perfectly..  My head will heal from all the head-banging to get this to work..
I hope this helps someone..

Comment: I was playing around with the umbracoSettings.config file.  It seems that the file can be blank..  I thought it was related to the "membership" section towards the end of the file, so I stripped everything but that out and it still worked.. even after resetting IIS and trying different browsers, etc.  in the end I cleared the file and it still worked..  then I renamed the file and it broke the site again..  renamed it back and presto, all working again.

Comment: Ads, what Umbraco DLLs must I add to my second application in order for the user management to work?

Comment: @amhed I added references to: busineslogic.dll, cms.dll, interfaces.dll, umbraco.dll, umbraco.providers.dll

Comment: @amhed I haven't tried to access any custom properties..  I didn't need to in my case, I just needed to authenticate users..  I'd be surprised if you couldn't..

Comment: This worked like a charm. Thank you sir! you're a gentleman and a scholar!

Comment: This didn't work for me! I'm on Umbraco 4.11 and I wasn't getting errors, I was just seeing 'unable to sign in' - I cut down the working project until I found the breaking change and it was removing the reference to Umbraco.Application in the global.asax - So with that in I can use the umbraco membership provider in another site, but it's a terrible solution - it's NOT an umbraco site, and umbraco is now creating a load of empty folders for me every time I build :( Anyone know what I'm missing?

Comment: Does anyone know if it's possible to use the admin loggin to secure the "not umbraco" app?